# jquery loop through form items return values with title, id appended

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

I am wanting to loop through all filled form items, input, select, radio, checkbox etc to extract the values.

The following code works nicely

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
$("#results").empty();
jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
$("#results").append(field.value + " ");
```

However, I want to append multiple attributes to the returned value such as name, id, title etc. Unfortuantely, my attempts at this are getting me nowhere.

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
$("#results").empty();
jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
var vTitle = $(each).attr('title');
$("#results").append(vTitle + " " + field.value + " ");
```

Does not work

Any help would be appreciated

cheers

Edit...
Thanks for the input but what is returned is 'undefined'. This is the HTML i am using

Edited to show all  contents

**Results:**

```
<form>
<select title="Staff:" name="single">
  <option>Single</option>
  <option>Single2</option>
  <option>Single3</option> 
 </select>
 <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
  <option>Multiple2</option>

  <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
 </select><br/>
 <input title="Staff:" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1"/>

 <label for="ch1">check1</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2"/>

 <label for="ch2">check2</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1"/>

 <label for="r1">radio1</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2"/>

 <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
<script>
function showValues() {
var fields = $(":input");
$("#results").empty();
jQuery.each(fields, function(i, v){
$("#results").append(v.title + " " + v.value + " ");
});
}

$(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
$("select").change(showValues);
showValues();
</script>

</body>
```

I need to see 'staff:' appended to the select value

This worked for me

```
function showValues() {
var fields = $(":input");
$("#results").empty();
var val;

jQuery.each(fields, function (i, v) {
        // if doesn't have checked property then get value - 
        // if checked return value 
        // else return empty string
        val = this.checked == undefined ? this.value : this.checked ? this.value : "";    
    if (val != ''){
            $("#results").append(v.title + " " + val + " " + v.id + "<br/> ");
    }
});
}
$("select,:checkbox, :radio").change(showValues);
showValues();
```

This loops through form elements and returns element value and title attribute only when element has a value...many thanks @wirey

Comment: if you want all the attributes don't use `.serializeArray()` - because that will only get you the `{name:inputname, value:inputvalue}`

Comment: Thanks...So what should i use instead?

Comment: your html doesn't match your jquery code at all :/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mistake in your last each-loop:

```
var fields = $(":input");
$("#results").empty();
jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
    var vTitle = $(this).attr('title'); // each should be called this
    $("#results").append(vTitle + " " + field.value + " ");
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your input...returns undefined not the title attribute value

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the fact that you had serializeArray in there. The edited answer should do the job

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
var vTitle = $(each).attr('title');
```

do

```
var vTitle = $(field).attr('title');
```

Comment: thanks for your input...returns undefined not the title attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) if you want access to other attributes besides the name/value..
jQuery docs states this

> Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.

```
var fields = $(":input");
$("#results").empty();
jQuery.each(fields, function(i, v){
   $("#results").append(v.title + " " + v.value + " ");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7bcTX/)

Comment: this returns attribute value but not value of form item

Comment: what do you mean?  How and when is this code getting trigger?  Can you create an example of jsfiddle.net to replicate your issue?

Comment: Your fiddle works with input boxes but if i change an element to a select list it fails to return the select list value

Comment: code is triggered when chnaging form item..see full HTML above..many thanks for your help

Comment: your code is confusing - you want to return the value the value of the checkbox or true/false?  Is this what you want? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2LJjc/)

Comment: i want to return the value of the checkbox...i only want to return id and title when an element has a value...thanks for your patience i'm new to this..but the fiddle is on the right track